# How to get Elapsed time from Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmx

I need to generate a token for every 2 hours (the expiration of token is 2 hours). How to get the time so that for every 2 hours I need to regenerate the token. Consider I need to perform a load test of 8 hours and every 2 hours the token should automatically generate it.

Is there any controller available in Jmeter for the above process. Any help will be much appreciated !!

Note: My test plan contains 2 thread group where first is to create the token and second is to perform the load test. As of now I am redirecting to generate token when previous request fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would configure 1st thread group to generate a token each 2 hours, i.e.

1. Set Loop Count to `-1` or tick `Forever`
2. Once you have your token generated use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to store it into a JMeter Property with any meaningful name, i.e. `token`
3. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler and configure it to `Pause` for `7200000` milliseconds
4. In the second Thread Group you can access the token value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(token)}`

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

JMeter Properties are global for the whole JVM therefore once the value is set in 1st thread group it will be immediately updated in 2nd thread group.